# ios swift uipickerview with 3 columns which have relations

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview

I want to make a uipickerview with 3 columns. But this columns has relation in database.
For example brands are first row. These are BMW,Seat,Mercedes ...
Brand's models are second row. These are 1 Series,2 Series,3 Series for BMW and Ibiza,Leon,Altea for Seat and so Mercedes have its own models. And three column is engine capacity. For example for 1 series 1.4,1.6..., for 3 series 1.6,2.0. And for ibiza 1.2TSI,1.4TSI, 1.6TDI and Leon and Altea and Mercedes' models have their own engine capacity.

In my DB i have three tables. First table is brand(brandId,brand). Second table is model(modelId,brandId,model) and third table is engineCapacity(id,brandId,engineCapacity).

If i have all these brand,model and engine capacity how can i show this relation to user? I mean if user select brand SEAT, second column only shows SEAT's models(Ibiza,Leon,Altea) and then user select Leon and third column only shows LEON's engine capacities(1.2,1.4,1.6).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` method `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`. In your implementation, if the user changes the brand (component 0) then call `reloadComponent(_:)` on the model and engine size components, and have the data source methods use the currently selected brand to determine which items to return for models and engine sizes.

(When you first display the picker view, have a specific brand and model selected, and populate the model component with the list of available models for the selected brand, and have the engine sizes component populated for the selected brand & model.)